# How can I edit files in a docker container when it's down/not-started

Tags: docker, edit, configuration-files

Use-case: I started some nice docker image and my container needs some playing around (configuration file changes for research). I edit a file (using sed or vim ;-) ) and then I stop the container and try to start it. Now I made a mistake in the configuration and the docker container does not come up when I do: `docker restart <my-container-id/-name>` How can I edit the configuration-file to fix the mistake?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Based on the advice of [jpetazzo](https://github.com/jpetazzo%20jpetazzo) (see https://github.com/jpetazzo/nsenter/issues/27#issuecomment-53799568) I started a different container that used the 'volumes' of the original container. Here is how:

```
docker run --volumes-from <my-container-id/-name> -it busybox
```

This will start a busybox shell. In there you have vi and other tools to inspect and fix the configuration-files.

Comment: This is the best solution, but the file should be in an exported volume for this to work. I'm not sure this is the case for OP.

Comment: Good to know it should be in an exported volume. I my case it was. Hence it did not come up as an interfering problem. Though this is an elegant solution, the answer of @elton-stoneman might prove a more solid solution.

Answer (score 6):

You can uses [docker cp](https://docker.github.io/engine/reference/commandline/cp/) to copy files to/from a container, whether it's running or not, and whether it has volumes or not:

```
> docker run --name temp alpine touch /file1.txt 
> docker ps
CONTAINER ID        IMAGE               COMMAND             CREATED             STATUS              PORTS               NAMES
> docker cp temp:/file1.txt .
> ls
file1.txt
```

Comment: A robust answer that will always work. I doubt which one to choose. I like the elegance of the solution I found earlier even when it does not always work. Up-voted yours and accepted mine (to share the 'glory' ;-) )

Answer (score 1):

Hello just create an image from the container and start it with bash then make the correction. Your container now starts with bash so you need to commit again and run it with your former command. And that's it:

```
docker commit <containerid>
docker images # to see the new imageid
docker run -it <imageid> bash
#Make the corrections and then exit bash
docker commit <containerid>
docker run <newimageid> formercommand
```

Regards

Comment: This will work, but the tools provided in the container might be to limited to edit the file. Hence I would go for one of the other answers.