# Command to move folders from one container to another container using Dockerfile

Tags: docker, docker-compose, dockerfile, docker-machine

I have pulled ubuntu16.04 and run docker image. I need to move all the folders to "mydistribution" folder inside docker image.

```
docker pull ubuntu:16.04

docker run -it ubuntu

root@cb3e5b5e75e9:/# ls
bin  boot  dev  etc  home  lib  lib64  media  mnt  opt  proc  root  run  sbin  srv  sys  tmp  usr  var
```

In my Dockerfile:

```
FROM ubuntu:16.04
USER root
ENV destpath mydistribution/ubuntu16.04
RUN mkdir -p mydistribution \
    && mkdir -p mydistribution/ubuntu16.04 \
```

COPY /. $destpath/ -> this will copy everything from current host folder to container, but instead of this, I want to move all the above folders (ls command output in container) into mydistribution/ubuntu16.04 using Dockerfile. I am not sure if we can do this or not, can someone help me to do the same, what will be the command to move them from container to another folder inside container?

Comment: Not exact duplicate, but essentially, `docker cp` [How can I edit files in a docker container when it's down/not-started](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40155622/how-can-i-edit-files-in-a-docker-container-when-its-down-not-started)

Comment: In Dockerfile, can we use docker cp command? I want to make docker image using ubuntu:16.04 (from dockerhub) and Dockerfile.

Comment: You can't use it in the docker file, but it doesn't really make sense to copy files out of a container on docker build. What are you trying to accomplish?

Comment: I need to use existing ubuntu:16.04 from docker hub but want the file system inside particular directory tree (which is expected to run shell script and generate dependencies)

Comment: What are you doing with the image that `docker build` produces?

Comment: I need to build a docker image which has ubuntu:16.04 file system inside particular directory tree with some extra scripts copied from host using Dockerfile which will be running as CMD from Dockerfile to generate some tar files when I run docker image

Comment: So you're copying files from one directory in the standard ubuntu image to  another directory inside the same image?

Comment: Yes, that is what I need to do. Because Dockerfile will already have one base image, but I need that base image inside particular directory tree structure, that's all. But looks like it is not possible. It is like I don't want base image but want ubuntu file-system in some folder using docker image.

Comment: Could you use regular bash `cp` command to make a copy of the files/directories you need?

Comment: I tried that, but the issue with that is, I have bigger size of docker image as there will be some base os needed in Dockerfile which will be again present in directory tree also. So ultimately it will be like copy of same file-system twice (first as base in Dockerfile's "From" statement and another inside container which I will copy from host.